# How can I add criteria based on a form field to an Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement

How do I get an operator to work in a query criteria based on a form field. Ideally I would like it to be something like:

```
IIf([Afloat]="No",<[Forms]![DASF]![Text222],"")
```

When I remove the operator it finds anything exactly to the criteria in that field but the moment I try to put an operator like greater than or less than it does not work. I am trying to find all records less than the value in that form field.

Any advice on how I can fix this? Or is it not possible in MS Access?

Comment: There's a few things wrong with your `IIF()` expression. First, the second argument should be a value and not logical expression. Second what value in query are you applying to the form field? You need a left-hand value. Next, `IIF()` is not a filter on all records but column-wise logic. Finally, what is your overall objective? Please post fuller query and some context.

Comment: You have the syntax correct for referencing the form field - you just need to pull the comparison out of the IIF statement and put it in front. Not sure what the other criteria is that you want, but I assumed you want it to be equal to ""? - see my answer below

Comment: I partly solved my problem by just separating into two queries (FLOAT and NONFLOAT) and then created a command button to open one or the other based on the "yes/no" criteria.

This however creates a new problem as I cannot figure out how to reference a bound text field within the form as my criteria for my query. The form auto-populates 12 text boxes based on what region is selected in the combobox. I am then trying to reference those bound textboxes as my criteria.

Ideas? Or should I submit it as a new question on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

QBF (Query By Form) can't accept operators in the formula.  Your only option is to write the query on the fly.  You can use the CreateQueryDef method to define the SQL in a specific query, and attach your form or report to the specific query name.

Something like:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim strSQL as String

Set db = CurrentDB
On Error Resume Next

'First, delete the query if it exists
db.QueryDefs.Delete "MyQueryName"

'Then, set up the query string
strSQL = "Select * From MyTable Where MyField < " & [Forms]![DASF]![Text222] & " and [Afloat] = 'No' "
strSQL = strSQL & "UNION "
strSQL = strSQL & "Select * From MyTable Where MyField = '' and [Afloat] <> 'No' "

'Now, recreate the query
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("MyQueryName", strSQL)
DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name
```

Comment: This statement is just not true "*QBF (Query By Form) can't accept operators in the formula*". Sure OP can't use it as he's attempting, but there's definitely ways to use the operators outside the IIF statement and combine it with other criteria lines

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the first criteria to:

```
>IIf([Afloat]="No",[Forms]![DASF]![Text222])
```

And then add a second criteria below it in the Or line:

```
=IIf([Afloat]<>"No","")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem by separating it into two separate queries. Below are my steps:

1. Instead of having a logical expression to decide I separated it into
   FLOAT and NONFLOAT queries.
2. Then I created a command button to open
   each query depending on the criteria in a combo box (yes or no).
   Here is the code:

   ```
   Private Sub Command2_Click()    
       DoCmd.SetWarnings False
       If Me.Combo272 = "Yes" Then
           DoCmd.OpenQuery "DASF_AGED_AS1_FLOAT", acViewNormal, acEdit
       Else
           DoCmd.OpenQuery "DASF_AGED_AS1_NONFLOAT", acViewNormal, acEdit
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
3. This created another problem, I was still unable to reference the txt boxes necessary for my query criteria. To solve this, I made all the text boxes unbound by using the below VBA to auto populate the text boxes based on another combo box. Here is the VBA I used:

   ```
   Me.Text220 = DLookup("REGION", "TDD_TABLE", "[ID]= " & Me.Combo236)
   ```